# WPF ItemsControl MultiConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

So, I have an ItemsControl bound to a collection of Items in an ObservableCollection.... As part of the DataTemplate I have two buttons one of which is passing the ItemsControl ItemsSource to a Multi Converter....

Here is the problem.... When I add an item to the CurrentTransaction.Items the Converter, GetPriceMultiConverter, is called just fine BUT when I remove an item from  CurrentTransaction.Items the  GetPriceMultiConverter is not firing BUT the UI is updating...

Here is the XAML

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="SalesScreen" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentTransaction.Items}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Width="225" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" Margin=".5" Content="{Binding DisplayName}" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveSaleCommand, ElementName=Screen}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
                <Button Width="90" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" Margin=".5" Command="{Binding DataContext.RemoveSaleCommand, ElementName=Screen}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
                    <Button.Content>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GetPriceMultiConverter}" >
                            <Binding ></Binding>
                            <Binding ElementName="SalesScreen" Path="ItemsSource" ></Binding>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Here is the bound property

```
    private Transaction _CurrentTransaction;
    public Transaction CurrentTransaction
    {
        get { return _CurrentTransaction; }
        set { _CurrentTransaction = value; OnPropertyChanged("CurrentTransaction"); }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see your relevant view model code?

Comment: "Any ideas" to why this happens? Obviously none of the two Bindings in the MultiBinding changes when an item is removed.

Comment: Try `Path="Items.Count"`; then `converter.Convert` will be called whenever the count of the items changes (ItemsSource.Count might work as well, same diff). What you've got will only update when `ItemsSource` is given a different collection. But `Count` still won't help if prices change on existing items -- if that's a concern.

Comment: That's the odd thing, the converter is called when a new Item is added to  CurrentTransaction BUT not when an Item is removed from CurrentTransaction....

Comment: That isn't odd at all. Besides that, it is unclear why you would need the converter to be called when an item is removed from the collection. For what reason?

Comment: @Clemens The converter needs to update (refresh) the remaining items in the ItemsControl to reflect that one has been removed.... It's odd because, despite the fact that the ItemsControl is updating (an item is removed correctly in the UI), that event isn't firing the Converter, neither the Convert or ConvertBack function is firing.

Comment: As said,  none of the two Bindings in the MultiBinding changes when an item is removed. Your approach won't work. You should instead update the remaining items in the view model.

Comment: If you're updating *properties of* viewmodel items in the collection in response to an item being removed, it's very unwise to have that be triggered by a converter in UI. That's very fragile. Strongly suggest you consider Clemens' suggestion that you do it all in the VM, if there's any kind of collection-changed event you can grab on the transaction Items

Comment: @Clemens The number of items in the ItemsSource collection is changing

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Not changing properties, the converter is selecting values to display (in the ItemsControl) based on the number of items in the collection, this works as the Items are added but not when they are removed... the Crux of the problem is that when removing an Item from the Collection, while the UI is updating, the converter is not firing....

Comment: @User45362 After getting an initial value, the converter will fire if and only if it gets a change notification event for one of the properties it is bound to. New `ItemsSource` object, change notification. If it's the same old `ItemsSource` object with changing contents, no notification ever, not until the end of time. You can add an extra binding that's ignored by your converter, just to get a notification from it: If and ONLY if any binding raises a change notification, the converter is reinvoked. Did you try adding a binding to the count of the items in the `ItemsControl`?

Comment: I don't know what `Transaction.Items` is, but *if* it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` it should raise `PropertyChanged` when the `Count` changes. So I'd test that and see. I think `SalesScreen.Items.Count` should raise an event as well on item count changes -- try that too if the other doesn't work.

Comment: The only way I can see of doing this (and letting the converter do all the work for you) is by removing ALL the items from you collection then add them again with the exception of the one you wanted to removed. BUT you can't do that very easily ether, for instance, in a foreach loop, notifications are 'stacked up' and will only be raised (thus call you converter) after the end of the loop, and all your items have been added again, that might not be the behaviour your looking for.

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Yes, I did try SalesScreen.Items.Count but now the darn converter is firing too often... But I can see the behaviour clearly now... After removing an item (binding to the Count property) the converter seems to be firing again for EACH item still in the collection... It's not gonna work, I'll have to try something else.... thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Right, it's in the item template so it happens for every row. I think that needs to be a singular VM property

Comment: @Ed Plunkett Yep, you're right, I have to save that value to the DB in any case so I need to get hold of it in code...